Visual Studio has stopped showing fix suggestions
For example if I have:
public class Something : ISomething

There might be a tooltip saying something like:
CSxxxx Something does not implement interface member ISomething.DoStuff
Usually there are also automatic fix suggestions in the tooltip, like:
Implement interface members...
But I'm no longer getting those suggestions! How can I fix that?
(VS2022, 17.10.1 on Windows 11. Reboot does not help.)

There is a bug with VS, workaround it by CTRL + .

Try it, put the cursor on ISomething and use alt+enter / ctrl + ., some fix suggestions will appear. Take a look at this section of the MS Doc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-and-fix-code-errors?view=vs-2022#use-quick-actions-to-fix-or-refactor-code
. I wonder if you have made any changes to your VS settings recently?
